# Why Strong memory model does not prevent cpu cache?

Tags: c#, memory-barriers

Joseph Albahari stated in his blog [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) that even on a strong memory order cpu (such as ordinary Intel Core-2 and Pentium processors),

> This following program never terminates because the complete variable is cached in a
>   CPU register. Inserting a call to Thread.MemoryBarrier inside the
>   while loop (or locking around reading complete) fixes the error.

```
static void Main()
{
  bool complete = false; 
  var t = new Thread (() =>
  {
    bool toggle = false;
    while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
  });
  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep (1000);
  complete = true;
  t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
}
```

As per [here](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/), this should not happen?

> A strong hardware memory model is one in which every machine instruction comes implicitly with  acquire and release semantics. As a result, when one CPU core performs a sequence of writes, every other CPU core sees those values change in the same order that they were written.

I'm confused with the 2 quotes, could anyone give me a more detail explanation?

Comment: First quote is about JIT time optimization ("You’ll need to run it with optimizations enabled") that simply removes all reads for `complete` variable - no amount of memory changes will impact value if it read only once.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with ordering or the processor memory model.  This issue is specific to the x86 jitter, its optimizer assumes that the variable can be stored in a CPU register and does not have to be reloaded from memory.  Since there are no other statements in the loop that might alter its value.  Declaring the variable as *volatile* is enough to convince it that this optimization is not appropriate.  That was the intention of volatile, before Microsoft abused it to try to tame the Itanium and screw up the C# memory model.  Volatile.Read() is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A strong hardware memory model is one in which every machine instruction comes implicitly with acquire and release semantics. As a result, when one CPU core performs a sequence of writes, every other CPU core sees those values change in the same order that they were written.

The memory write order is not important in this example. As the thread keeps constantly polling it will eventually pick up the updated value of `complete` variable.

However, this is related to memory and cache which must present the same view to all processors. Registers are private per cpu and don't have to share their contents with other cpus.

The `complete` variable is in the register of thread t. There is no way any other processor can update this register because it is actually not linked to memory system. Making the variable `volatile` will solve the issue as it will keep it in memory and not register.

> This following program never terminates because the complete variable is cached in a CPU register. Inserting a call to Thread.MemoryBarrier inside the while loop (or locking around reading complete) fixes the error.

Both these fixes basically keep the variable in memory for it to work.